# Running Spark jobs on Yarn and the amount of memory it uses

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a simple Spark job on our Hortonworks cluster.

I just see from metric that, before running my job, there is 310gb from 640gb memory usage. However, when I run my job, it becomes 324gb from 440gb.

My job just takes 12gb from cluster but not sure why total available memory of the cluster decreases when I run the job.

It was first 324gb out of 640gb, then becomes 324gb out of 440gb, 324gb out of 320gb and then becomes 324gb out of 328gb, according to the metric reported by Ambari dashboard in Yarn memory panel.

I am not aware of any configuration on our cluster but is this could be due to a configuration which limits the usage of yarn memory below a threshold?